# C++ digit separators in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++14, literals

Using visual studio 2015 from command line. Options used: `/std:c++14`

Whenever I try to compile

```
int num = 10'000'000;
```

cl.exe says `warning: digit separators not enabled, apostrophe begins a character literal`

How do I enable it?

Comment: `/std:` is a command line parameter for gcc/g++.  Take a look at the `/Zc` parameter, if that helps. There may not be an equivalent for  MSVC.

Comment: Also, that syntax of `int num = 10'000'000` works fine without any special command line parameters in VC2015.  (I'm running VS2015 with Update 2 if that helps).

Comment: @selbie https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt490614.aspx

Comment: `/std:c++14` was introduced in vs2k15 update 3.

Comment: Thanks.  That explains it. I'm on update 2.  Time to upgrade.